# python+security

Tags: python, security, sockets

what would be a good way to implement an authentication in python? something that already exists is fine too.
I need it for auth over an untrusted network connection. It doesn't need to be advanced, just enough to get a common password over securely.
i have looked at the ssl module. but that module confuses me like there's no tomorow.

long story short: I want ssl or something similar to work. if someone could explain it to me it'd be great.

it's a client-server system. the client can't be trusted, anyone can 'decompile' python. i do need to handle connections from arbitrary clients. as soon as the secure connection is made i can start doing the actual auth using password checksums and whatnot. i'd rather not send plaintext checksums as that'd be pretty darn easy to spoof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously HTTPS is a good choice, if you do not need encryption, [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) can provide a secure authentication alternative, [and seems to be supported in python](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html).

Comment: hmac seems to be what i need. but in what way is it not encrypted? if you don't know the key you can't get the message. right?

Comment: ah, okay. got it. but you misread, i can do the auth myself. but only after i got a secure connection. a shared secret is no problem.

Comment: It's an alternative for using a secure connection (which is an obvious possibility), since it authenticates the message and the peer without compromising the authentication credentials

Comment: well yes. but i do want the information encrypted. thinking about it i might just do symetric encryption.